# The biquadratic character of $2$ mod $p$ for a prime of the form $p=4n+1$

Tags: nt.number-theory

It seems that Gauss states the following theorem in his first paper on biquadratic residues(Werke vol. II pp. 67-92). I cannot read Latin, but I have a Japanese translation of the paper. However, it is difficult to decipher the paper even in Japanese. Is the theorem right? If yes, how do you prove it?

**Theorem** Let $p$ be a prime of the form $p = 4n+1$. Let $g$ be a primitive root mod $p$. Let $f\equiv g^{(p−1)/4}$ (mod $p$). Then $f^2\equiv −1$ (mod $p$). It is well known that $p=x^2+y^2$ has an integer solution $(a,b)$. Suppose $a$ is odd and $b$ is even. $a$ is uniquely determined by the condition $a\equiv 1$ (mod $4$). $b$ is uniquely determined by the condition $b\equiv af$ (mod $p$). Suppose $2\equiv g^\lambda$ (mod $p$). Then $\lambda\equiv b/2$ (mod $4$).

**Remark**
I asked the same question in Math StackExchange.
Since nobody answered it so far and it seems that the question is highly non-trivial, I post this question here.
Since I was suspended recently there, I'd appreciate if somebody would kindly add the link of this question to my question there.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/471023/the-biquadratic-character-of-2-mod-p-for-a-prime-of-the-form-p-4n-1

This is a related question in MSE:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/470976/the-number-of-solutions-of-ax4-by4-equiv-1-mod-p-for-a-prime-of-the-f

Comment: For starters, $f$ should be $g^{(p-1)/4}$, not $(p-1)/4$, which is not a square root of $-1$ except for $p=17$.

Comment: you want the pdf by Liu_Williams, from http://zakuski.utsa.edu/~jagy/inhom.html  The final result is that 2 is a fourth power for $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ if an only if $p = x^2 + 64 y^2.$ Cox, in Primes of the Form $x^2 + n y^2,$ says Gauss did prove that in his first memoir, but did not really give an acceptable account of cubic and biquadratic reciprocity in the second memoir. These were cleaned up by Eisenstein and Jacobi. Page 87.  For details he refers to Ireland and Rosen.

Comment: I can't say that I'm a fan of using MO to circumvent MSE suspensions.

Comment: @CamMcLeman What exactly do you mean by "to circumvent MSE suspension"? Does it mean using MO instead of MSE?
What's wrong with it as long as questions are appropriate here?

Comment: I have posted a link at m.se to the question here.

Comment: Some people downvoted for this and my other questions which were posted today.
If they did it just because I was suspended in MSE,
that would be outrageous. MO is *NOT* MSE.

Comment: If you are interested, you can read my activities in MSE.meta and guess why I was suspended.
Particularly the meta question titled "Why my comments were deleted from this question?"

Comment: @MakotoKato, could you actually link to the relevant meta questions?

Comment: @ScottMorrison The list may not be exaustive.
Older threads show earlier.

[T1](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10580/whats-wrong-with-this-question)

[T2](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10634/should-a-near-duplicate-meta-question-not-be-posted)

[T3](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10643/should-a-non-homework-question-not-be-given-a-full-answer)
[T4](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10650/old-questions-with-hint-only-answers-can-we-provide-whole-answers)

[T5](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3838/proper-use-of-homework-tag)

Comment: @ScottMorrison [T6](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8998/closing-questions-that-show-no-effort-official-policy)

[T7](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10675/why-my-comments-were-deleted-from-this-question)

[T8](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10697/please-undelete-my-answer)

[T9](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10634/should-a-near-duplicate-meta-question-not-be-posted)

[T10](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10706/please-undelete-my-question)

Comment: @ScottMorrison I wrote a comment to a moderator Alex Becker in [T7](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10675/why-my-comments-were-deleted-from-this-question) which says "I want you to be careful when you delete a comment. It may be important for the thread just like in this case".
I've just noticed that it was deleted by someone.

Comment: And maybe now people will not even have to read those threads to get an idea of the cause for suspension, seeing as there are 10 of them, most of them quite recent (within a few days).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I'm not sure about your idea.
Could you explain more clearly your idea of the cause for suspension?

Comment: I think it's safe to say that the majority of the moderators of MSE don't agree with me on my opinions for homework and non-homework questions.
I guess it's relevant to my suspension.
Namely I *generally* disagree with banning questions which show no effort and I *generally* disagree with hint-only answers.

Comment: You generally cause a lot of noise by creating multiple threads on subjects that have already been discussed previously at length without even bothering to acknowledge that previous discussion or apparently reading it.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I knew there exist similar old threads.
I disagree with banning to open a near-duplicate question on *meta*.
Please see [T9](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10634/should-a-near-duplicate-meta-question-not-be-posted).
I answered or commented on some old threads in the above list.
Do you think this is also frowned upon?

Comment: This isn't the appropriate place for this discussion.

Comment: @ScottMorrison [This isn't the appropriate place for this discussion.]
No, but your question, which is off topic, was one of the causes of the discussion.
[MakotoKato, could you actually link to the relevant meta questions?]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, this theorem is correct.

From quartic reciprocity we obtain $(2/p)_4 = i^{ab/2}$, or in other words, $2^{(p-1)/4} \equiv f^{ab/2} \pmod p$. (There is an elementary proof of this fact due to Dirichlet: see Exercise 4.24 in Cox, "Primes of the Form $x^2+ny^2$.) So if $2 \equiv g^\lambda \pmod p$, then $f^{ab/2} \equiv g^{\lambda(p-1)/4} \equiv f^\lambda \pmod p$, and consequently $\lambda - ab/2 \equiv 0 \pmod 4$.

Comment: there is a second edition, inexpensive http://www.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-1118390180.html

Comment: seems Ireland and Rosen is still at the second edition http://www.springer.com/mathematics/numbers/book/978-0-387-97329-6

Comment: Thanks. Please wait for a few days before I accept this.